# Whole word regex match

Tags: java, regex

I have a list of strings, like `c++`, `c`, `java`, `c#`, `.net`.

I have to find the occurrences of these strings in some text.

I tried,

```
String pattern = "(?i)\\b"+Pattern.quote(str)+"\\b";
```

But it doesn't match with `c++`.

Then, I removed `\b` and it started matching every `c` in the text.

How do I match the whole word?

**Sample String**:

> C, c#, C++ college cat cow

Comment: give use what word you are trying to match and we will create the regex for it

Comment: I already mentioned. There are several of them like c++, c, java, .net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\bc\+\+\b` cannot `c++` because `+` is not considered a word character. `\b` can only match after a word character not after a non-word character like `+`.

You can probably use this regex:

```
\bc\+\+(?=\W|$)
```

[Regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/jA3oM6/1)

Comment: how do I make it work for every string. Is there a way to do that? Or will I have to explicitly check for `+` character in my string?

Comment: You can use this for other strings also. Even `\bJava(\b|$)` will also work.

Comment: I tried both of them but it didn't match all of them. Am I missing something? I have provided the sample string and looking for words `c`,`c#`,`c++`

Comment: What is value of `str` in your code?

Comment: I'm iterating a list. It can be any of the words like `c`,`c++`,`c#` which are present in the list.

Comment: See it working here: http://regex101.com/r/jA3oM6/1

Comment: great, that works! Just a question here. I'm noob. What is the difference between `(?=\s|$)` and `(?=\W|$)`?

Comment: `\W` matches any non-word character but `\s` matches a whitespace only.